# Bitmapfactory error

Tags: java, android

I'm using fairly 'standard' code to try and download an image from a url as follows:

```
private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url){

        try{
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

It fails at this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

where it jumps to the catch block.

Using debug in Eclipse, it seems to run ok, and the variable 'bytes' seems to have a bunch of stuff in it, and the url I pass in does show an image in a browser.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be here, or more importantly how I can debug it myself (new to Eclipse, Java, Android)? eg I've no idea what to do with e.printStackTrace(); to allow me to actually see something (despite a lot of Googling), there's nothing showing in Logcat and nothing in the Eclipse console

Thanks

Comment: Go to window -> show view -> LogCat to see the output from calls such as Log or printStackTrace. In the stacktrace you can see lots of information such as on what line in you cod an exception occurred and what kind of exception it was. With this information it will be much easier for you (or us) to find what the actual cause is.

Comment: LogCat has no error info in it nor anything that points to the issue, nor has the Eclipse Error Log nor the Eclipse Console

Comment: If that is the case, what makes you certain that you end up in the catch-block? Also make sure that you do not have any active filters in LogCat that blocks out the errors.

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the line 'Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);' and then Step Over, whereupon the next line it jumps to is the 'return null;' in the catch block

Comment: I see, you should get an errormessage though. Have you tried EntityUtils.toString() to see what your received data is?

Comment: I added the line 'String stringbytes = EntityUtils.toString(entity);' and it also jumps to the 'return null;' line in the catch block, but nothing appears in LogCat. (I had to comment out the existing EntityUtils line, as that did throw an error in LogCat about the entity already having been consumed)

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the returned entity in that case?

Comment: Add : Log.er("Error", e.getMessage()); in the catch clause and you'll see something appear in the logcat telling you what might cause the problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to execute any lines within the catch block - Step Over jumps from the BitmapFactory line to the return null; line in the catch block. No log messages I put in there get printed in LogCat, but messages I out elsewhere do

Comment: Ok, you need to stop debugging :) The fact that you try to debug while connecting to a server may be the problem you don't see anything wrong. Maybe the connection times out while you are debugging. Run the program with no break points and put Log.e messages before and after the bitmapfactory call and leave the one in the catch block. Then check your logcat, you should see the path taken by the code.

Comment: That worked... thanks. debugging made it look like it was throwing an error, but running it was ok

Answer (score 0):

Check that the image you are trying to decode do not contain a color profile. It happened to me. The BitmapFactory does not know how to handle those and crashes with no meaningful error.

To check for color profiles, if you have photoshop, just try to open it and it might popup a screen asking you what to do with the color profile. Alternatively, on Mac, right-clicking on the file and choosing "more info" you can see a color profile line.

Comment: Can't see anything that looks like a color profile line - also I've tried it on a jpg and png image - I assume it should work with either of those?

Comment: If you don't see the color profile line, it's probably not the same problem. But since I had the same symptoms and this is what resolved it, I had to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Debuggers generally go to the return statement...it doesn't get executed though...you can try with a normal function as well...The best way to find whther there is an exception is to print some logs inside the catch block.